# libGDX AssetManager local file not found after successfully downloaded

Tags: java, libgdx

I am developing an app for both Desktop and Android. Same behavior on both platforms.

I am using the AssetManager to load images from a **local** path (see [libGDX file handling](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling#file-storage-types)).

```
AssetManager assetManager = new AssetManager();
FileHandleResolver resolver = new LocalFileHandleResolver();
assetManager.setLoader(Texture.class, new TextureLoader(resolver));
```

Initially, there are no images available. So if I click a button which triggers the assetManager to load an image, let's say test.png, it obviously produces a file not found error.

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load dependencies of asset: test.png
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: test.png
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: test.png (Local)
```

Nothing surprising here, so far so good.

But here is the problem: I'm able to download pictures and store them locally with a click on another button. The download works with no problems. But if I try now to load a downloaded image the assetManager is still throwing the same exceptions.

I verified that the files are actually saved, on Android and Desktop. And the interesting thing is that after I restart the Desktop or Android app, the files get loaded successfully. So it seems to me, that there is some kind of "file refreshing" missing somewhere. The files get stored, but somehow they are not available directly after the download.

Any ideas?

Comment: why are you loading your texture in a local file and not on internal?

Comment: It needs to be local storage since I need to download the images from a server at runtime. Internal storage is read only, see libGDX doc. And external storage isn't an option either because the data should not be visible to other applications.

Comment: have you tried changing your file path to lower case? because sometimes android will read only lower case and will ignore the upper case

Comment: can you get a screen shot where your files at? and how are you loading it like assetManager.load("pathName",class);